# Support #-locations for questions, answers, (votes?), tags on profile pages

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

It should be possible to link directly to the answer list (sorted by votes) or the active tag list.

The information about the account owner at the top of the page is pretty boring if the link is on an external page which already provides those information. But linking to my answers which got many votes or the tags i am active in adds value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of there already, but a shorter id might be better and might *look* (or *be*) more future-proof?

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137430/nhnb?sort=votes#questions-table
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137430/nhnb?sort=votes#answers-table
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137430/nhnb?sort=votes#tags-title

Comment: Oh, i wasn't aware that firefox supports and id-attribute in #-references. Does the tags-title one work in other browsers, too?

Comment: Yes, it's not a Firefox thing, @nhnb. Just part of the specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3